# Google Fit - Daily step count seems to be tallying incorrectly

Tags: android, google-fit

Why is my Google Fit tally my daily step count incorrectly.

Here, based on 12 entries, my Google Fit app is telling me I walked 2,465 steps:

[image: img]

But if I add up the individual constituents, it works out to 55+4+10+231+90+1979+20+13+49+13+28+7 = 2499 steps.

So what gives? Why is the total daily count Google Fit is telling me I walked short by those 34 steps? I have an app that's connected to Google Fit's SDKs which is also tallying up the total daily counts, and so when I noticed the discrepancy there and couldn't find an issue with my app, I came back to google fit to check if the issue originates here.

Comment: Could be due to syncing delays. If you read by your app's data source rather than by data type, and your app only uses local step data, the step count will be different from the step count in the Google Fit app.

If you're reading the data types but values are still different from the Google Fit app, this temporary difference in numbers could be due to syncing delays.